# Internet sharing on MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt, internet-sharing, ethernet

I'm trying to share my MacBook Air's wireless connection to my PS3 via ethernet and internet sharing. In internet sharing the share to options are iPhone USB, Thunderbolt Bridge and Bluetooth PAN. If I buy a USB-Ethernet adapter will I be able to share my internet connection through it or do I have to purchase the more expensive USB-Thunderbolt adapter? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up purchasing [this cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ET4KHJ2) and it works for internet sharing as both an input and output. When it is plugged in, a new option in the internet sharing preferences appears.

Comment: I'd recommend the native Apple USB Ethernet Adapters after a few years with several third party versions in service together with some Apple originals. There are mysterious kernel panics which sometimes pop up with the third party versions. It does stick in one's throat to pay $30 for what should cost $10 or $15 even with Apple margins. Kernel panics are still worse though.

Answer (score 1):

You should pick a thunderbolt cable, since it clearly states "iPhone USB" which a playstation with USB to ethernet adapter isn't.

Why don't you connect with the PS3 wireless directly if I may ask?

Comment: I meant to use the usb to connect to my computer and the ethernet to the ps3. The PS3 hasn't been picking up any wireless signals.

Comment: Buying a cheap router which your playstation can find is a cheaper and better solution then, it is weird that your PS cannot find wireless - but that's not Apple.StackExchange

So what you're actually trying to do is a work-around instead of fixing the wireless issue on your PS3